# How to copy the form values

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I have written two forms

```
<g:fom name ="report_html" action="htmlReport">
    <g:render template="/templates/filterTemplate" />
    <input type ="submit" value ="Generate Html Report" id ="html_report_submit"> 
</g:form>
<g:form name ="pdf_report" action = "pdfReport">
  <input type ="submit" value ="Generate Pdf Report" id ="pdf_report_submit"> 
</g:form>
```

_filterTemplate.gsp has many fields

Now ,i want when the form "report_html" is submitted the values should be available so that when the "pdf_report" form is submitted the same values should be passed.so how to copy the form elements and used for the other form .

Answer (score 0):

Access them via `$("#ElementID").val()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use two hidden field and keep thos in sync with some javascript:

```
<g:fom name ="report_html" action="htmlReport">
  Start Date: <input type ="text" name ="startdate" id ="startdate" value=""> 
  End Date: <input type ="text" name ="enddate" id ="enddate" value=""> 
  <input type ="submit" value ="Generate Html Report" id ="html_report_submit"> 
</g:form>
<g:form name ="pdf report" action = "pdfReport">
    <input type ="hidden" name ="startdate" id ="startdatecopy" value=""> 
    <input type ="hidden" name ="enddate" id ="enddatecopy" value=""> 
  <input type ="submit" value ="Generate Pdf Report" id ="html_report_submit"> 
</g:form>

$('#startdate, #enddate').keyup(function(){
    var id = '#'+this.id+"copy";
    $(id).val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: actually ,the form content is displayed through Template ,it has got many fields ,but i have shown only two fields ,see my edit

Comment: @Vinay, but why don't you have the two buttons submit the same form and then server side do different things according to the button pressed?

Comment: actually in the first form ,the showReponse method is generating the html content. so the pdf content is not display properly

Comment: and the output of the first form will be customized .so if i give the two different actions in the same form , output of the html report will be correct but some junk values will display for pdf report